# grails link - add javascript variable into params

Tags: javascript, grails

```
$('#andiebox').append('<g:link controller="search" action="search" params="[where:'+destination+', what:what, sort:sort, type:type, distance:distance]">Psychos in HH</g:link>');
```

this is not accepted by grails, how can i insert the variable correctly?

the variable is clientside generared from a input:

```
var destination = $(this).attr("id");

            var metaSection = $("#metaSection").val();
```

Comment: is `destination` server-side on client-side variable?

Comment: Then how do you expect to parse it server side?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`<g:link` is server-side tag, so it could only prepare base to your link. All client side parameters should be filled on client side. Something like:

```
var params = { 
   what: '${what.encodeAsJavaScript()}', //as I understand all this variables are server side variables
   sort: '${sort.encodeAsJavaScript()}', 
   type: '${type.encodeAsJavaScript()}', 
   distance: '${distance.encodeAsJavaScript()}' 
}; 
params.destination =  $(this).attr("id");
var urlBase = '${createLink(controller:"search", action: "search").encodeAsJavaScript()}';

$('#andiebox').append('<a href="' + url + '?' + $.serialize(params) + '">Psychos in HH</a>');
```

Comment: To be safe you should use `var urlBase = '${createLink(...).encodeAsJavaScript()}';`, and similarly for the params values (`what:'${what.encodeAsJavaScript()}', ...`) in case any of them contain characters that need special handling in JavaScript string literals.

Comment: Uncaught TypeError: Object function (e,t){return new v.fn.init(e,t,n)} has no method 'params'