# Grails file download - client side

Tags: ajax, file, grails, download

I'm trying to download a file using grails. I've followed a few solutions on this site and I think the file is being passed back correctly from the contoller. I can see the files contents when I examine the data being passed back.

However the download doesn't start. I'm unsure on what should be on the client side.

I'm calling this contoller action using jquery.

```
File fd = new File(filename)
        response.setContentType("application/octet-stream")
        response.setHeader("Content-disposition", "attachment; filename= ${fd.getName()}")
        response.outputStream << fd.newInputStream()
        response.outputStream.flush()
```

And here is the jquery 9I need to pas the filename as a paramater:

```
    jQuery.ajax({
            url : "/dev/image/download",
            type : "GET",
            data : {
                image : imgData
            }
        });
```

I'm not sure what way to go from here. Most of the examples I'm seeing only deal with the contoller side. I'm unsure about how the client side should be configured.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of calling download with AJAX request, create a link to it. See if that helps.

```
<g:link action="download" id="1" params="[...]">download</g:link>
```

you can pass parameters into your link, however, if your params are created in your javascript you can still send them but a different approach.

take a look at this post by [Igor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11037614/pass-javascript-variable-into-createlink-method-call-grails) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15479074/grails-link-add-javascript-variable-into-params)

Comment: Would it be posiible to pass the image variable like this? its just a String but it gets created in the javascript right before where I had the ajax call?

Comment: What is the image variable? What is its value?

Comment: its a string of an xml file. The xml is created dynamically so I have it set up so that whatever state its in when the user clicks download it will be sent to the server.